# document.getElementById("main").innerHTML not displaying or working

Tags: javascript

I have main.html, test.html and script.js in the same folder. I'm using a Python package called Eel, and that's how I'm interacting with html and Javascript. When I call function dummy() as shown below, I get a print statement from Python, which is exactly what I want, but when I change the "main" to "test" in the dummy() it doesn't print anything. Why is that? How come script.js knows about "main", but not about "test"?

main.html

```
<div>
        <p id="main">This is from main.html</p>
        <input type="submit" name="" onclick="dummy()"></input>
<div>
```

test.html

```
<p id="test">This is p tag in test.html</p>
```

script.js

```
function dummy() {
        u = document.getElementById("main").innerHTML
        eel.dummy(u)
}
```

Comment: Because there is no element in your html with id "test".

Comment: unclear how main.html and test.html are related..... You expect code on main to read content on test???

Comment: `getElementById` does exactly that. You do have an element with an `id` of `main`, but you do not have an element with an `id` of `test` in the `main.html` file. Are you referencing `script.js` from each file?

Comment: @devd I have <pre><p id="test">This is p tag in test.html</p></pre> with "test"

Comment: I guess my question is, how come script.js know there's a "main" in main.html, but it doesn't know there's a "test" in test.html.  main.html and test.html are in the same folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browser-side JS runs in the context of the webpage it is associated with.

The script is in *main.html*.

The element with `id="test"` is in *test.html*.

That's a *different document* and not accessible to JS running in *main.html* (at least not unless you use something like an `iframe`, but even then it would still be a different document and you'd have to access *that* document through the iframe's API).

Comment: Let me see if I can share my both html and script.js.

Comment: https://ibb.co/FYtYmQT
https://ibb.co/ns494Jt
https://ibb.co/3zddz2K

Comment: I added 3 screenshots, hope this will help.

Comment: By script is in main.html, are you talking about the onclick = dummy()?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm really not familiar with JS, I mostly code in Python (as a hobby).  If you look at the images, you can see that I'm using script.js in main.html and test.html

Comment: You're **calling the function** in *main.html*. That fact that you load the same function into a different page when that page is visited doesn't matter.

Comment: Ok, so I can only call the function in one html?

Comment: No. You just can't access an element that isn't in the document you are running the JS in at that particular moment.

Comment: Ok, I understand now.  Sorry, I code for hobby, and this is my first time doing JS.  Then what's the solution?  I'm assuming I would have to figure out a way to pass "test" to the main.html so it knows about it?

Comment: The problem is rather too abstract to identify a good solution. It would be anything from "Get the data with Ajax from a webservice instead" to "Put the data you need in the page you are actually running the function in." to "Use server side code to inject a `<script>` with a call to the function in the other page when you navigate to it with a particular flag from the previous page" to something else entirely.

Comment: ok, I wish there was something like document("test.html").getElementById("test").innerHTML = whatever

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm going in the right path, because I'm not familiar with Ajax, I don't want to go that way.  Anyway, I put <body onload="test()" in test.html, and test() in script.js with t = document.getElementById("test")
 t.innerHTML="hi it works"

Comment: Instead of onload, is there like a onfunction so it can do it when I call the dummy() in main.html?  I know this is confusing, but just trying a bunch of stuff

Answer (score 0):

I think you did not add **script.js** to **main.html**  (but added that to **test.html** )

**script.js** will work with id=**"main"** only if you added the js file to **main.html** file.

check the demo: I do not have access to **python-eel** so can not use **eel.dummy(u)** in the code snippet, instead, I just changed the value of another **p tag**.

```js
function dummy() {
        u = document.getElementById("main").innerHTML
        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = u
}
```

```html
<div>
        <p id="main">This is from main.html</p>
        <input type="submit" value="Click" onclick="dummy()"/>
        
        <p id="test"> text to be changed</p>
<div>
```